# What is the smallest margin an Australian Federal or State seat has ever been won by?

Tags: voting, australia

What's the smallest difference between the winner and the next party in any state or federal election in Australia. Interested in both percentage and absolute count.

Comment: Are you interested in just margins for one candidate winning over another candidate, or also cases where the order in which candidate elimination involves a small difference?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I'm  interested in one candidate Winnie over the other after the preferences are tallied. I'm not sure what you meant for the other scenario

Answer (score 4):

The smallest margin ever recorded ([according to the Australian Parliament](https://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/Parliamentary_Departments/Parliamentary_Library/pubs/rp/rp1314/AustPolRecords)) was **seven votes** in 1914. From the link:

> John Lynch (ALP) defeated Alfred Conroy (LP) by just seven votes
>   (13,162 to 13,155) to win the seat of Werriwa (NSW) at the 5 September
>   1914 election. There have been contests where the margin was less but
>   in both cases the result was challenged and the election declared
>   void.

In more recent times, at the 2016 federal election, the seat of Herbert in QLD which was lost by incumbent Ewen Jones to Cathy O'Toole by [just 37 votes](https://results.aec.gov.au/20499/Website/HouseDivisionPage-20499-165.htm).